# Why is my React Router NavLink for '/' maintaining its activeClassName when I navigate away from it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a navbar with three  components/links. The structure looks like this:

```
<ul className="flex text-white flex-col lg:flex-row list-none lg:ml-auto">
    <NavLink
       activeClassName="active"
       to="/"
     >
        Home
     </NavLink>

     <NavLink
       activeClassName="active"
       to="/about"
      >
        <span className="ml-2">About</span>
      </NavLink>

     // etc
```

I have it connected to a BrowserRouter which correctly changes to the pages that are passed into the `<Route>`'s, so I believe I have set this all up correctly.

```
<div className="App">
  <Navbar />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</div>
```

I have the class 'active' in my App.css file to change the button font color to red. This works, but the issue for me is that the /home link never loses its active class. Example image:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Am I missing something obvious here?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3rHD.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm using the same version as you are but I've always used isActive on NavLinks to determine if they are active or not.

```
<NavLink to="/" isActive={(match, location) => {
  return location.pathname === "/";
}} activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
```

Just did a quick search and found this which might be helpful: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `exact` for the root `<NavLink/>` too,

```
 <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
```

like so ^

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-sidebar-forked-dd724?file=/example.js:1210-1279